# How to include apply and function together with multiple ifelse condit

Tags: r, function, apply

I am new to R programming and completely stuck in finding a solution for below problem.

I have a data set 'full_data'(near to 80 variables) but short as :

```
CustomerID   ReachRatio CustomerGrade  PolicyCount
1             10          Loyal         2
2             40          Normal        6
3             80          VIP           11
4             100         Normal        7

CustomerID: sequence of unique ID
Reach :a score out of 100 for customer based on contact details
CustomerGrade: It has label as 'Normal','VIP','Loyal' or 'To be   calculated','NA' and 'Uncalculated' etc
PolicyCount:No of policy brought by customer in a timeframe so >5 is good
```

I want to  write a single function in r to compute a score for these 3 customers based on a weightage as:
/* this code is not working*/

```
full_data$CustomerScore = apply(full_data,1,function(row)
  (((ifelse(row["CustomerGrade"]=='LOYAL',1,0)*30)+
      (ifelse(row["CustomerGrade"]=='NORMAL',1,0)*20)+
      (ifelse(row["PolicyCount"]>=4){ 1*30})+
      (ifelse(row["ReachRatio"]>=40 && row["ReachRatio"]<=80,1,0)*40)))
)
```

So my final outcome for example  CustomerScore is a value out of 100 based on weightage applied to each category.in the above code Customer grade:total weight:30(if loyal--30,normal--20,else--0)
policy count:weight:30[in case elobrated can have more values but total wt is 30]
Reach ratio weight:40[eg if >80--40 ,>40 && <80--20...]

How to implement it efficiently in R?

Any suggestions and ideas are welcomed!!

Thank you so much !!

Comment: Could you show more number of rows?  Are you saying that 100 is the expected output? BTW, the comparison with `==` will be exact matches.  lowercase/uppercase matters

Comment: I have updated the code..Thank you!!

Comment: Are you expecting 3 scores for each user respectively or a single score?

Comment: Expecting a single score in one function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
apply(X = df,MARGIN = 1,function(row){
    ifelse(row["CustomerGrade"]=='Loyal',30,0)+
    ifelse(row["CustomerGrade"]=='Normal',20,0)+
    ifelse(row["PolicyCount"]>=4,30,0)+
    ifelse(row["ReachRatio"]>=40 && row["ReachRatio"]<=80,20,0)+                                  
    ifelse(row["ReachRatio"]>80,40,0)})

#[1]30 70 40 50
```

Comment: @DeviVijayakumar it helped but did it not actually solve your problem? If it did, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you,but somehow the function is returning 0 for all values

Comment: @DeviVijayakumar Could you please share output of `head(dput(df))`. You can restrict the number of columns to those shown in the question description by `df[,c("colname1","colname2"...)]`

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to loop through the rows.  This can be vectorized.  Based on the logic used in the OP's `ifelse` statements

```
with(df1, sum(30*(CustomerGrade =='Loyal')+
              20*(CustomerGrade == 'Normal') + 
              30*(PolicyCount >=4) + 
              40*(ReachRatio>=40 & ReachRatio <=80)))
```

Comment: I think the weight has to be 20 when ReachRatio is between 40-80, and  weight is 40 when ReachRatio is greater than 80.

Comment: @tushaR  I am following the OP's code `row["ReachRatio"]>=40 && row["ReachRatio"]<=80,1,0)*40`

Comment: Unfortunately,the function is giving '0' for all rows

Comment: @DeviVijayakumar  Not for me and it is based on your logic